Why can't we apply this theorem to prove that the integral equals $0$?
For $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z+i)^2(z-i)}$ we want to show: $$\int_{S_1(i)} f(z)dz \neq 0$$ where $S_1(i)$ is the circle of radius $1$ around $i$.
We can parametrize $S_1(i)$ to obtain an integrand that is positive and conclude that this integral is in fact not zero.
My question is why I can't use the following theorem to prove that it equals $0$. There must be some condition that I'm missing.:
Theorem:
Let $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded region, which is bounded by finitely many non-intersecting, closed, piecewise smooth curves $C_0, C_1, \ldots, C_n$, which are positively oriented. If $f$ is holomorphic in $G$ and continuous on all $C_i$, then it holds that
$$
\int_{\partial G} f(z) \, dz = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \int_{C_i} f(z) \, dz = 0.
$$
We can choose $G:=B(i,1) \setminus \{i\}$, then $\partial G=S_{1}(i)$.
Now $f$ is holomorphic on $B(i,1) \setminus \{i\}$ and continuous on a parametrization of $S_1(i)$. Hence the integral would be $0$.

$\partial G\ne S_{1}(i)$.

Thank you, that's it. i belongs to this set as well. Hence the last part doesn't work
